# Finding all users within X miles calculation via mysql is slow

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with this query. It takes about 5 seconds to run against ~300 users. I assume it's because it's calculating the distance for every possible user.

Is there a way for me to optimize this to make it run fast? Thanks in advance.

```
select
        t2.*,
        t2.city,
        t2.state,
        t2.county,
        ifnull(round((6371 * acos( cos( radians('32.7211') ) * cos( radians( t2.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( t2.longitude ) - radians('-117.16431') ) + sin( radians('32.7211') ) * sin( radians( t2.latitude ) ) ) ),0),1) AS distance
     from
        users t1
     inner join
        zipcodes_coordinates t2
        on t1.zip_code=t2.zipcode
     having
        distance <= 150
```

Comment: Make sure you have the relevant columns indexed. If you do already, it's always helpful to say so in your question.

Comment: This would be considered de-normalization, but you could have a column with cos(radians(td.latitude)) and cos(radians(td.longitude)) already calculated, and change 6371 * acos( cos( radians('32.7211') ) into a constant in your query, as that will never change.

Comment: @Zoidberg I'd argue it would be faster overall, over the course of a day, to derive those trigs than to read the extra bytes for them from disk.

Comment: @jgbubby, I would argue it would be faster to have those values calculated already, you would have to read 2 columns regardless... either two columns with lat and long, or a column with the calculated lat and long.  However, I would agree your answer is intuitive and implements a strategy I never considered.  Your answer is definitely a good one and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would eliminate as much of the data as you can *before* the main bit of the query is run, which you list. Your query is almost certainly looping over every single row in the table.

For example, you know that if a user at (X,Y) is within an R mile circle of a certain point X',Y', then they are *certainly* within a square of diameter 2R, which means the following things hold:

```
X <= X' + R
X >= X' - R
Y <= Y' + R
Y >= Y' - R
```

So to make a query on the database, you could first have the database eliminate all users who's X value doesn't satisfy those constraints, and this can be done using the index on the field. (same goes for the Y co-ordinate)

Another (rather more domain-specific) trick would be to split the world up into small squares that are indexable with a single identifier (could be a long, or even a string with the co-ordinates of the centre so long as you could re-create them reliably from any co-ordinate within the square). Then store which square each co-ordinate is in as well as the co-ordinate itself. If you are looking for e.g a 5 mile radius, then make the squares something like 2 miles square. That way you can very quickly do a search on a small number of adjacent squares by identity (it would be no more than 9 in this case), then loop over the results in those squares to find the closest matches in your application.

Most performance optimisations in this kind of thing are about *eliminating* data that certainly doesn't fit and then refining, rather than immediately going after data that certainly does.

PS - if you are using MySQL there is a GIS extension, which I haven't tried: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/gis-with-mysql.html. This probably does something like what I describe, and may or may not take into account the curvature of the earth, etc. However in most cases the successive refinement method is fairly safe, and means your database doesn't have to 'know' about GIS co-ordinate systems.